# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy con un ejercicio de la agenda de clientes. Ahora se me pide listar a los clientes con atención al nif, se me pide que introduzca una función de nombre `listar` con parámetros por defecto y que si el nif introducido no es correcto muestre todos los clientes.

Tengo puesto esto (sólo pongo la parte de esta función):

```
numero=int(input('Introduce el nf del cliente requerido:'))
letra=input(('Introduce la letra: ').upper())
def listar(numero,letra=str):
      if len(numero)!=8 or numero is not int:
            print (clientes)
      if letra is not str or len(letra)!=1:
            print (clientes)
      return
listar(numero)
```

Me da este error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-9f11af7cac8a> in <module>
     52             print ('Ha introducido una opcion erronea')
     53         return
---> 54 menu()

<ipython-input-24-9f11af7cac8a> in menu()
     39                     print (clientes)
     40                 return
---> 41             listar(numero)
     42         elif opcion==3:
     43             print ('Ha introducido la opcion borrar cliente')

<ipython-input-24-9f11af7cac8a> in listar(numero, letra)
     34             letra=input(('Introduce la letra: ').upper())
     35             def listar(numero,letra=str):
---> 36                 if len(numero)!=8 or numero is not int:
     37                     print (clientes)
     38                 if letra is not str or len(letra)!=1:

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

¿Cómo puedo contar el número para que sean 8 dígitos, ni más ni menos?

Comment: Entiendo por el código que  `numero`  ya debería ser un entero, por lo que  `len(numero)!=8` estaría de más, o más bien no correspondería

Comment: Pero si lo meto por teclado con input, lo introduce como un string, no?

Comment: O más bien sería `len(str(numero))!=8` en todo caso

Comment: Si pero, estas convirtiendo a un `int` luego del input

Comment: Debes revisar para que casos es válido que uses [len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)

Comment: Si bien es posible que el parámetro de una función pueda recibir distintos tipos de dato, lo habitual es asumir que cada parámetro sea siempre de un único tipo. En este caso `numero` debería ser siempre o una cadena o un entero, pero no ambos.

Comment: No consigo que me funcione, necesito asegurar que el número introducido por pantalla tiene 8 dígitos y una sola letra, (además de imprimirlo en una sola línea si es correcto, que antes no lo he puesto en el código, gracias de todas formas seguiré intentándolo

Answer (score 1):

Tu error esta en que no puedes medir la longitud de un numero como entero `len(numero)`, pues esto dara un error, solo puedes medir la longitud de *Strings* o cualquier variable que puedas contar sus elementos.
Ademas `numero is not int` esta de mas, ya que el parametro sera el valor del input `numero` el cual ya lo has transformado a entero. Y en caso el usuario ingrese una letra, esto dara un **ValueError** diciendo que este dato es una cadena literal y no se puede expresar en base 10.

por ultimo al decir que letra sea opcional y establecer su valor con `str` esto esta mal, ya que lo que se le asignara a `letra` sera el objeto `str` que alfinal retornara la clase `__str__()` por lo que mejor es que pongas otro valor en forma de cadena, por ejemplo `" "`

**La funcion**

```
def listar(numero,letra=" "):
      if numero!=8:
            print (clientes)
      #tambien puedes comprobar que sea diferente de vacio
      if letra is not str or len(letra)!=1: 
            print (clientes)
      return
```